# Как выйти из редактора git-rebase-todo?

Tags: git

Читаю всякие спецификации по GIT типа "[6.4 Инструменты Git - Перезапись истории](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)"
Там пишется, что команда

```
$ git rebase -i
```

запускает тестовый редактор коммитов.
Далее пишется:

> Когда вы сохраните и выйдете из редактора ...

И не слова о том как это сделать.

Подскажите. Как сохранить изменения и корректно выйти из редактора git-rebase-todo?
Работа ведется в Git Bush для Windows.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выйти из редактора Vi или Vim?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437417/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-vi-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не переназначали редактор, то скорее всего у вас открылся **vim**. Для того, чтобы выйти из него, наберите `:wq` и нажмите Enter. Перед этим убедитесь, что vim не находится в режиме вставки (слово **INSERT** внизу). Если находится, то перед набором команды нажмите Esc. Если же вы перенастроили редактор, просто сохраните изменения и закройте его.

Как настроить редактор сообщений коммитов, написано [здесь](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git). Как работать с vim - [здесь](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vim).